# Can you `svn status` the remote repository instead of you local working copy?

Tags: svn

Is there an `svn` command to check which files would be downloaded from the remote repository if one should issue an `svn update`?

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but this question is a lot easier to read than the one it's linked to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.show_updates

`svn status --show-updates`

---

Maybe you could use a specific `svn info` too?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html

Comment: Short version: `svn st -u`

Answer (score 6):

SVN does offer a `--dry-run` option but unfortunately this does not work with `svn update`.  You can however mimic the behaviour of `svn update` using `svn merge` appropriately and that does support the option.

So, use the following:

```
svn merge --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD .
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - not listing local modifications, just what has changed from Base to Head! Thank you :)